# `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, definition, category-theory

This is yet another Haskell-through-category-theory question.

Let's take something simple and well-known as an example. `fmap`? 
So `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, omitting the fact that `f` is actually a `Functor`. As far as I understand, `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is nothing but a **syntax sugar** for the `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`; hence conclusion:

**(1)** `fmap` is a function producing a function.

Now, **Hask** contains functions as well, so `(a -> b)` and, in particular, `(f a -> f b)` is **an object** of the Hask (because objects of the Hask are well-defined Haskell types - a-ka mathematical sets - and there indeed exists set of type `(a -> b)` for each possible `a`, right?). So, once again:

**(2)** `(a -> b)` is an object of the Hask.

Now weird thing happens: `fmap`, obviously, is a **morphism** of the Hask, so it is a function, that takes another function and transform it to a yet another function; **final function hasn't been applied yet**.

Hence, one needs one more Hask's morphism to get from the `(f a -> f b)` to the `f b`. For each item `i` of type `a` there exists a morphism `apply_i :: (f a -> f b) -> f b` defined as `\f -> f (lift i)`, where `lift i` is a way to build an `f a` with particular `i` inside.

The other way to see it is `GHC`-style: `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. On the contrast with what I've written above, `(a -> b) -> f a` is mapping to the regular object of the Hask. But such a view contradicts fundamental Haskell's axiom - no multivariate functions, but applied (curried) alternatives.

---

I'd like to ask at this point: is `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` suppose to be an `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b) -> f b`, sugared for simplicity, or am I missing something really, really important there?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185639/discussion-on-question-by-sereja-bogolubov-a-b-c-d-in-haskell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` suppose to be an `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b) -> f b`, sugared for simplicity

No. I think what you're missing, and it's not really your fault, is that it's only a very special case that the middle arrow in `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)` can be called *morphism* in the same way as the outer `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)` can. The general case of a Functor class would be (in pseudo-syntax)

```
class (Category (──>), Category (~>)) => Functor f (──>) (~>) where
  fmap :: (a ──> b) -> f a ~> f b
```

So, it maps morphisms in the category whose arrows are denoted `──>` to morphisms in the category `~>`, but this morphism-mapping itself is just plainly a *function*. Your right, in **Hask** specifically function-arrows are the same sort of arrows as the morphism arrows, but this is mathematically speaking a rather degenerate scenario.

Comment: Yeah, agree, your example is quite explicit and yet redundant for programming language. But still - why not be a little bit explicit by default and force `GHC` to refer `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`. `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is WAY MUCH unusual abuse of notation!

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov It's not an abuse; there just aren't any other common right-associative, non-commutative operators to use for intuition. There is *no* ambiguity about what `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` means. Because it is right-associative, the only possible parse is (switching to prefix notation) `(->) (a -> b) ((->) (f a) (f b))`.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Do you also object that `3 * 4 * 5` is an abuse of notation, and that we should be forced to write either `(3 * 4) * 5` or `3 * (4 * 5)`? What about `1 - 2 - 3` or `f $ g $ x`? If you agree it is okay to have a notion of which way operators associate by default at the computation level, then why not at the type level, too?

Comment: @DanielWagner, see the comments under the other answer. That resolves all issues.

Comment: @DanielWagner `3 * 4 * 5` isn't a great analogy, because that's unambiguous even _without_ a notion of which way operators associate. (At least for exact arithmetic.)

Answer (score 5):

`fmap` is actually an entire *family* of morphisms. A morphism in **Hask** is always from a concrete type to another concrete type. You can think of a function as a morphism if the function has a concrete argument type and a concrete return type. A function of type `Int -> Int` represents a morphism (an endomorphism, really) from `Int` to `Int` in **Hask**. `fmap`, however has type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. Not a concrete type in sight! We just have type variables and a quasi-operator `=>` to deal with.

Consider the following set of concrete function types.

```
Int -> Int
Char -> Int
Int -> Char
Char -> Char
```

Further, consider the following type constructors

```
[]
Maybe
```

`[]` applied to `Int` returns a type we could call `List-of-Ints`, but we usually just call `[Int]`. (One of the most confusing things about functors when I started out was that we just don't have separate names to refer to the types that various type constructors produce; the output is just named by the expression that evaluates to it.) `Maybe Int` returns the type we just call, well, `Maybe Int`.

Now, we can define a bunch of functions like the following

```
fmap_int_int_list :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
fmap_int_char_list :: (Int -> Char) -> [Int] -> [Char]
fmap_char_int_list :: (Char -> Int) -> [Char] -> [Int]
fmap_char_char_list :: (Char -> Char) -> [Char] -> [Char]
fmap_int_int_maybe :: (Int -> Int) -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
fmap_int_char_maybe :: (Int -> Char) -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Char
fmap_char_int_maybe:: (Char -> Int) -> Maybe Char -> Maybe Int
fmap_char_char_maybe :: (Char -> Char) -> Maybe Char -> Maybe Char
```

Each of these is a distinct morphism in **Hask**, but when we define them in Haskell, there's a lot of repetition.

```
fmap_int_int_list f xs = map f xs
fmap_int_char_list f xs = map f xs
fmap_char_int_list f xs = map f xs
fmap_char_char_list f xs = map f xs
fmap_int_int_maybe f x = case x of Nothing -> Nothing; Just y -> Just (f y)
fmap_int_char_maybe f x = case x of Nothing -> Nothing; Just y -> Just (f y)
fmap_char_int_maybe f x = case x of Nothing -> Nothing; Just y -> Just (f y)
fmap_char_char_maybe f x = case x of Nothing -> Nothing; Just y -> Just (f y)
```

The definitions don't differ when the type of `f` differs, only when the type of `x`/`xs` differs. That means we can define the following *polymorphic* functions

```
fmap_a_b_list f xs = map f xs
fmap_a_b_maybe f x = case x of Nothing -> Nothing; Just y -> Just (f y)
```

each of which represents a set of morphisms in **Hask**.

`fmap` itself is an umbrella term we use to refer to constructor-specific morphisms referred to by all the polymorphic functions.

With that out of the way, we can better understand `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Given `fmap f`, we first look at the type of `f`. We might find out, for example, that `f :: Int -> Int`, which means `fmap f` has to return one of `fmap_int_int_list` or `fmap_int_int_maybe`, but we're not sure which yet. So instead, it returns a *constrained* function of type `Functor f => (Int -> Int) -> f Int -> f Int`. Once that function is applied to a value of type `[Int]` or `Maybe Int`, we'll finally have enough information to know which morphism is actually meant.

Comment: `(a -> b)` is a morphism, it is well-understood notation. `(a -> b) -> f a` *could be* interpreted is such a way that there exists a morphism from the `(a -> b)` to the `f a`. Saying that `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`, would rather mean that morphism is mapped to another morphism, and no uncertainty remained! That's what I was asking - what's the point to introduce such a weird context-based uncertainty, if there is no syntax sugar staying behind?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov It is merely a matter of notational convenience. Putting `fmap` aside for a moment, it is convenient to be able to write `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` rather than `(+) :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)`, or `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` rather than `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> (t a -> b))`

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov It can only be interpreted that way if you willfully ignore the associativity of the `->` operator. *Don't do that!* Do you complain that `1 + 2 * 3` could be interpreted as `(1+2)*3 == 9`? No, because you don't ignore the fact that `*` is assumed to have a higher precedence.

Comment: Well, I pointed out from the very beginning - it is **category theory specific question**. Arrows are not operators - the compositor is. Arrows have no precedence. Arrows are just arrows - unless the context is provided. In Hask arrows are just functions: do functions preserve associativity? Nope, however function composition - does.

Comment: The whole reason for dropping the parentheses is to maintain the illusion of multi-argument functions, a mental model that is usually (but not always) more useful than a higher-order function. When the less-commonly used interpretation is desired, *then* you can apply the extra work of the redundant parentheses to emphasize the point.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov A question involving the syntax of Haskell type signatures is not purely about category theory, though.

Comment: Haskell is not category theory, though - despite the fact that parts of Haskell are obviously deeply based on certain ideas of category theory. Haskell *does* have an "arrow operator", which is right associative and where `a -> b` denotes a morphism (or function, in programming terms) from type `a` to type `b`. It's a convenience which sits on top of the category-theoretic underpinning. But it doesn't contradict or somehow go against anything from category theory.

Comment: But `fmap` is *not* an arrow, which is where this simple substitution breaks down. Categorically speaking, there are two separate adjunct functors that we choose to "merge" into a single operator `(->)`. You might want to read https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/03/13/function-types/, which explains categorically what a function type actually is, and mentions `curry` and `uncurry`. (Somewhere in Zmilewski's book is also a discussion about how adjunct functors apply to all this, but I forget where at the moment.)

Comment: @chepner. that's nice hint! Much appreciated. I had to specify that this is not just Haskell-specific question in a more explicit manner, apologizes for long misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks @chepner - I'd missed that point, and still aren't too sure about it myself, but I'll definitely read that article, which looks interesting!

Answer (score 3):

> Now weird thing happens: fmap, obviously, is a morphism of the Hask, so it is a function, that takes another function and transform it to a yet another function; final function hasn't been applied yet.
>
> Hence, one needs one more Hask's morphism to get from the (f a -> f b) to the f b. For each item i of type a there exists a morphism apply_i :: (f a -> f b) -> f b defined as \f -> f (lift i), where lift i is a way to build an f a with particular i inside.

The notion of application in category theory is modelled in the form of [CCC's - Cartesian Closed Categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category). A category  is a CCC if you have a natural bijection (X×Y,Z) ≅ (X,Y⇒Z).

In particular this implies that there exists a natural transformation  (the evaluation), where [Y,Z]:(Y⇒Z)×Y→Z, such that for every g:X×Y→Z there exists a g:X→(Y⇒Z) such that, g = g×id;[Y,Z]. So when you say,

> Hence, one needs one more Hask's morphism to get from the (f a -> f b) to the f b.

The way you go from `(f a -> f b)` to the `f b`, or using the notation above, from `(f a ⇒ f b)` is via `[f a,f b]:(f a ⇒ f b) × f a → f b`.

The other important point to keep in mind is that in Category Theory "elements" are not primitive concepts. Rather an element is an arrow of the form →X,where  is the terminal object. If you take X= you have that (Y,Z) ≅ (×Y,Z) ≅ (,Y⇒Z). That is, the morphisms g:Y→Z are in bijection to elements g:→(Y⇒Z).

In Haskell this means functions are precisely the "elements" of arrow types. So in Haskell an application `h y` would be modelled via the evaluation of h:→(Y⇒Z) on y:→Y. That is, the evaluation of (h)×y:→(Y⇒Z)×Y, which is given by the composition (h)×y;[Y,Z]:→Z.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, this answer focuses on a point that was addressed in various comments, but not by the the other answers.

> The other way to see it is GHC-style: `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. On the contrast with what I've written above, `(a -> b) -> f a` is mapping to the regular object of the Hask.

`->` in type signatures is right-associative. That being so, `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is really the same as `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`, and seeing `(a -> b) -> f a` in it would be a syntactic mix-up. It is no different from how...

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

... doesn't mean that partially applying `(++)` will give us an `[a]` list (rather, it gives us a function that prepends some list).

From this point of view, the category theory questions you raise (for instance, on "need[ing] one more Hask's morphism to get from the `(f a -> f b)` to the `f b`") are a separate matter, addressed well by [Jorge Adriano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53900363/2751851).